# KeyStore service with hard limits

Tags: amazon-s3, limit, quota, key-value-store

I'm putting together a datastore technology that relies on a backing key-value store, and has Typescript generator code to populate an index made of tiny JSON objects.

With AWS S3 in mind as an example store, I am alarmed at the possibility of a bug in my Typescript index generation simply continuing to write endless entries with unlimited cost. AWS has no mechanism that I know of to defend me from bankruptcy, so I don't want to use their services.

However, the volume of data might build for certain use cases to Megabytes or Gigabytes and access might be only occasional so cheap long term storage would be great.

What simple key-value cloud stores equivalent to S3 are there that will allow me to define limits on storage and retrieval numbers or cost? In such a service, a bug would mean I eventually start seeing e.g. 403, 429 or 507 errors as feedback that I have hit a quota, limiting my financial exposure. Preferably this would be on a per-bucket basis, rather than the whole account being frozen.

I am using S3 as a reference for the bare minimum needed to fulfil the tool's requirements, but any similar blob or object storage API (put, get, delete, list in UTF-8 order) that eventual starts rejecting requests when a quota is exceeded would be fine too.

Learning the names of qualifying systems and the terminology for their quota limit feature would give me important insights and allow me to review possible options.

Comment: Deleted my answer. Please clarify the fact that you're going to store gigabytes of data. That's not in your question. But crucial. It's not clear to me what your usecase is. What kind of data has gigabytes of key-values pairs? And are these properties grouped in any way?

Comment: Good idea. I will revisit the question. Although the long term answer is essentially any data (I am building an indexing technology inspired by CouchDB collation - indexes in JavaScript over Btree keystore) the use case for experimenting is hosted notetaking (e.g. allow anyone to use the system with volume limits on a freemium model - which could build up). Adding a fulltext index to any good number of notes will grow fast ( 1 mapped object per word per including doc, plus 1 reduced object for the index) but initially be only tens of megabytes I guess. Multiple users would multiply that

Comment: Added detail on potential for arbitrary and volume data.

Comment: I found that Backblaze B2 has an S3 compatible API and a cost cap per bucket.